# Can I make my UiApp draggable?

Tags: google-apps-script

Using Google Apps Script, I've made a UI for use on a Google Spreadsheet.

When called, it appears in the centre of the spreadsheet. I'd like to make it draggable so the user can move it out of the way if necessary - they may need to change cell selection whilst the UI is active.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a title, then you can drag it 'by the title' ;-)

example :   `app.setTitle("drag me here");`

Comment: Serge you are such a star! Thank you!